# Change lock timeout for SQLConnection (sqlite database) in Flex/AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sqlite, locking, timeout

I use sqlite in Flex with `flash.data.SQLConnection`

How to change lock timeout? The standard timeout is too small and when running inserts from two computers I get lock errors?

I could run query after error again but it would be better if lock timeout would be set i.e. 2-5 seconds.

Comment: Never seen this, are you connecting with Sync or Async?

Comment: generally with Async, but I could change it if it would help :)